# Unable to change my input types values on edit page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, edit

When i add my users values then it will add from add user page. But when click on edit link and go to edit page. i am unable to edit values like firstname,lastname etc. Please check my below code.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import Header from '../Header/Header.jsx';
import Footer from '../Footer/Footer.jsx';
import { userActions } from '../_actions';

class EditUser extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            edituser: {
                first_name: '',
                last_name: '',
                username: '',
                email: '',
                active: '',
                user_type: '',
                profile_image: '',
                social_link: '',
                remove_by_admin: ''  
            },           
            submitted: false
        }; 
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.dispatch(userActions.getUserDetails(this.props.match.params.id)); 
    }

    handleChange(event) { 
        const { name, value } = event.target;
        const { user } = this.state;
        this.setState({
            user: {
                ...user,
                [name]: value
            }
        });
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({ submitted: true });
        const { user } = this.state;
        const { dispatch } = this.props;         
        if (user.first_name && user.last_name && user.username && user.email && user.active && user.user_type && user.profile_image && user.social_link && user.remove_by_admin) {
            user.id = this.props.match.params.id;
            dispatch(userActions.updateUserDetails(user));
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { user, users,edituser } = this.props; 
        let editUserData = '';
        if(edituser.edituserdetails) {
            editUserData = edituser.edituserdetails;
        }         
        const {submitted } = this.state;
        return (
            <main className="wrapper">
                <Header />
                <div className="wrap_content update_profile">
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="heading_block mb_24px"><h2 className="p_ttl">Edit Profile</h2></div>
                        <div className="content_block">
                            <div className="row upd_prof_cont">
                                <form className="theme_form" name="addCompanyForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                                    <div className="col-md-4 aside_sidebar">
                                        <div className="aside_content">
                                            <div className="upl_cmp_logo white_box">
                                                <p>Profile Image</p>
                                                <div className="files_dropzone">
                                                    <input type="file" className="upl_inp_file" name="profile_image" /> 
                                                    <div className="comp_profpic">
                                                        <figure><img src="images/cmp-logo1.png" alt="" /></figure>
                                                        {submitted && !editUserData.profile_image &&
                                                            <div className="help-block">Profile Image is required</div>
                                                        }
                                                    </div> 
                                                </div> 
                                            </div> 
                                        </div>
                                    </div>   
                                    <div className="col-md-8 article_desc">
                                        <div className="article_content">
                                            <div className="white_box update_details"> 
                                                <div className="form-group">
                                                    <div className="fiels_row">
                                                        <div className="half_col">
                                                            <label className="lable-control">First Name</label>
                                                            <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="First Name" name="first_name"   value={editUserData.first_name} onChange={this.handleChange}  />
                                                            {submitted && !editUserData.first_name &&
                                                                <div className="help-block">First Name is required</div>
                                                            }
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div className="half_col">
                                                            <label className="lable-control">Last Name</label>
                                                            <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" name="last_name"   value={editUserData.last_name} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                                                            {submitted && !editUserData.last_name &&
                                                                <div className="help-block">Last Name is required</div>
                                                            }
                                                        </div> 
                                                    </div> 
                                                </div> 
                                                <div className="form-group">
                                                    <div className="fiels_row">
                                                        <div className="half_col">
                                                            <label className="lable-control">Email Address</label>
                                                            <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="eamil" readOnly value={editUserData.email} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                                                            {submitted && !editUserData.email &&
                                                                <div className="help-block">Email is required</div>
                                                            }
                                                        </div>  

                                                        <div className="half_col">
                                                            <label className="lable-control">Username</label>
                                                            <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username"   value={editUserData.username} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                                                            {submitted && !editUserData.username &&
                                                                <div className="help-block">Username is required</div>
                                                            }
                                                        </div>  
                                                    </div> 
                                                </div> 
                                                <div className="form-group">
                                                    <div className="fiels_row">
                                                        <div className="half_col">
                                                            <label className="lable-control">Social Links</label>
                                                            <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Social Links" name="social_links"  value={editUserData.social_links} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div className="half_col">
                                                            <label className="lable-control">Active</label>
                                                            <select name="active" className="form-control" onChange={this.handleChange}>
                                                                <option value="1">active</option>
                                                                <option value="0">Not-active</option>                                                                
                                                            </select>  
                                                        </div>                                              
                                                    </div> 
                                                </div>   
                                                <div className="form_submit">
                                                    <button className="btn btn-primary btn-theme"><i className="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i>Update Profile</button>
                                                </div>   
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </div>      
                <Footer />
            </main>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    console.log('state',state)
    const { users, authentication,edituser } = state;
    const { user } = authentication;
    return {
        user,
        users,
        edituser
    };
}

const connectedEditUser = connect(mapStateToProps)(EditUser);
export { connectedEditUser as EditUser };
```

Comment: put code in http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @masoudsoroush

Please check this screenshot. https://prnt.sc/lwh718. 

When i try to change my firstname like "Pritesh" to "Pritesh123". So i am unable to edit. its showing like readonly. Can you please help.

Comment: screen shot not useful for debug!
first of all: let editUserData = ''; should be an object!
secound: put user details in state,
third: on change form update state,
finally submit the state

Answer (score 2):

You are reading the user data inside render method from the props. Example

```
<label className="lable-control">First Name</label>
<input value={editUserData.first_name} type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="First Name" name="first_name" onChange={this.handleChange}  />
```

where editUserData is derived from `this.props.editUser` (First line in render method)

But the `handleChange` method sets the data inside the state of your component. So the updated first name is inside your component's state but the first name in the props will still remain the same.

You should either make your component stateless and read only from props (and update the user details through a handler provided by a parent which maintains the state) or you shouldn't read from the props at all and let your component have its own state and read from the state.

Read more about how to avoid common mistakes in this pattern - [here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-controlled-component)

EDIT: Here is an even more detailed blog on how this pattern can be avoided or made safe - [Click here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html)